# Web Browser on firemonkey mobile application file chhoser not working

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have an application on firemonkey mobile. there is a web browser component and go an url adress. in my web application i upload a file with file chooser. the application work in any web browsers on android or ios phone. but not work when i build the app for android apk or ios. the Web browser on application go to the url and work fine but when that i want to upload file with file chooser i click the file chooser but nothing happens. how do i upload files in my web application using firemonkeys web browser

Comment: Can you provide a part of web app? What is RAD Studio version?

Comment: i use rad studio XE8. there is a link for test http://www.biges.com/mobile/test.aspx when i click choose file button not happen.

Comment: It will be wise to make an issue in Embarcadero quality portal, https://quality.embarcadero.com